# Any experience with the Visual Studio Shell?

Tags: visual-studio

Our company is considering using the [Visual Studio Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx2008/products/bb933751.aspx) for one of our products.

Does anyone have any experience using it?  Was it easy to work with?  Did it save time?  Are there any things that you weren't able to get it to do?  Have you shipped anything with it?

Comment: Great question! To bad you asked it on a Friday afternoon :(

Comment: My project is planning on using it for our designer.  It looks like the learning curve is crazy steep.  The only way to learn it right now is pretty much to examine some of the examples out there and do what they did.

Answer (score 2):

**A couple of points regarding the Isolated shell.**

As you might know, there are two considerations when you use shell - Isolated Mode and Integrated Mode. ([Read more from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx2008/products/bb933751.aspx))

Isolated Shell can be used by organizations, to build applications that run side by side with other editions of Visual Studio.

Here are some points we learned,
    trying to use shell for some of our
    applications.

- If you are planning to use Isolated
  shell, you can't use Microsoft
  Language Packages like C# and VB.NET
  inside that.
- Creating a package for your shell is
  much like creating any other VS
  Package.
- You don't have support for Team
  Explorer and VS Built in Source
  Control access, in Isolated Shell
  ([See this post from Vin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404/source-control-in-visual-studio-isolated-shell))

Though not directly related - If you are using VS SDK 1.1 to develop your packages - remember that the managed package framework is no longer available with the default distribution. So don't get surprised if your old packages can't load MPF files after moving to SDK 1.1.  It has got moved to Codeplex as a separate download.

Answer (score 1):

I played around a bit with it a couple of weeks ago, like every thing there is going to be a learn curve but if you study the examples a bit and have a look at a project on codeplex called Storyboard designer.  I'm sure that you could pick it up, I found it very hard to find other examples on the net but I wasn't looking very hard.

I would say if you think that the shell can give you want you need I would go for it, it is a very handy interface to work with and if your targeting developers it is also a common interface for them, so it will feel natural.

Answer (score 0):

I typically use `Visual Studio Community` on my PC for developing business intelligence solutions (databases, SSIS, SSAS, SSRS), then deploying to the server.  A few weeks ago my managers requested we put Visual Studio on a server so that other developers and consultants could connect to the server and access Visual Studio.

Ultimately I installed **`SQL Server Data Tools (14.0.61021.0)`**, which automatically installed **`Visual Studio Shell 2015`**.  After installation, I launched Visual Studio Shell and tried doing some of the things I am used to doing in Community edition. I was able to do pretty much anything I was used to doing for BI Development.

> **Visual Studio Shell 2015**:
>
> - Solution files with BI projects...
>
>   - SSIS
> - Installing extensions & add-ons...
>
>   - ANKHSVN for version control with SVN server
>   - Visual Studio 2015 Color Theme Editor
> - Project deployment